# SQLite SELECT query in Android external database - table error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing a data collection app using multiple relational data tables. I've created my database. And the code is working fine in case of the first table. If I try to run the same query for the second table, it shows the table doesn't exist, even though the table is in the database.

Database structure

[image: Database structure]

```
public String getName(String Plant) {
    c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from Area where PAd = '" + Plant + "'", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String plant = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + plant);
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dbtest, PID: 28350
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Area (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Area where PAd = 'Plant02'
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1392)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
        at com.example.dbtest.DatabaseAcess.getName(DatabaseAcess.java:46)
        at com.example.dbtest.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:86)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Table structure of the second table

```
 CREATE TABLE Area (
    Name    TEXT,
    Address TEXT,
    PAd     TEXT
 );
```

Table structure of the first table

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
   Name    TEXT,
   Address TEXT
);
```

`DatabaseOpenHelper` code.

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyExternalDatabase1.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

`DatabaseAccess` code.

```
public class DatabaseAcess {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAcess instance;
    Cursor c = null;
    Cursor c1 = null;

    private DatabaseAcess(Context context){
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public static DatabaseAcess getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new DatabaseAcess(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void open(){
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        if(db!=null){
            this.db.close();
        }
    }

    public String getAddress(String name){
        c= db.rawQuery("select Address from Table1 where Name = '" + name + "'", new String[]{});
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String address = c.getString(0);
            buffer.append("" + address);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public String getName(String Plant) {
        c1 = db.rawQuery("select Name from Area where PAd = '" + Plant + "'", null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String plant = c.getString(0);
            buffer.append(""+plant);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your database structure . is Area table created at the time of executing this query?

Comment: share the code in onCreate() of SQLite Database

Comment: Yes Area is created.

Comment: `Yes Area is created` ... then you should not be seeing this error message.  You should show us the code which you think is creating this table.

Comment: Its an external database, there is no code to create table only to access and read database

Comment: @RakeshKumar, I think this is not the problem.

Comment: @JJIqbal instead of adding a picture of the error, you might consider posting the error log as text, so that it is easier for the developers to find the problem they are facing.

Comment: @JJIqbal, try this `db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Area WHERE PAd = ?", new String[] {Plant});`

Comment: @ReazMurshed, yes that will help us to trace out the error

Comment: Please post your sqlite class

Comment: Great to see that you edited your question with the error log. Kudos! 
Please check my answer below and let me know if that helps! Thanks.

Comment: execute this ( select * from sqlite_master where type='table') sql by your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by the external database, you meant a database which you want to be loaded from your `asset` directory. Here you need to copy the database in your application internal storage first to make this accessible from your code. So I would like to suggest you do the following when you run the application for the first time.

```
public static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + "com.your.package.name" + "/databases/";

private void copyFromAssetsAndCreateDatabase() {
    InputStream yourDatabaseFromAsset;

    try {
        yourDatabaseFromAsset = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyExternalDatabase1");

        File dir = new File(DataHelper.DB_PATH);
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
        File f = new File(DataHelper.DB_PATH + "MyExternalDatabase1" + ".sqlite");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;

        while ((mLength = yourDatabaseFromAsset.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);

        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInputEnglish.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now when the database is copied from your external folder to your internal storage where the databases are located usually, it should find the database without any error. I do not know about the first database though. I think it was created in your application using the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, but my first table query is running similar to this one running fine. I think it is accessing database.

Comment: Is your first table was created using code (`Create table`) from your application? And what about the second table? Is it created from your application code as well?

Comment: Please share the `onCreate` function of your `DatabaseOpenHelper`. Where you have put the `Create Table` function.

Comment: I do not see any create table statements there. Did you try my solution?

Comment: Iv'e acknowledged your idea, mean to get a copy of database in assets into project folder. But its the issue with code, I couldn't efficiently use it . Could you elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you

```
public String getName(String Plant) {
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Area WHERE PAd='+Plant+'", null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String plant = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append(""+plant);
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that you created only first table at first time. After that you append code for second table. Note database is already created and will not call onCreate() again. You should upgrade database version and create second table in onUpgrade().

I made same mistakes before.